# query logging in MariaDB on Windows 10

Tags: mariadb, mysql-slow-query-log, mariadb-10.4

How to enable {all type of, not just slow} query logging to FILE in MariaDB Server version: 10.4.11 running on Windows 10 ?
I have modified my.ini file and added these line at the bottom but it did not worked

[mariadb]
log_output=FILE
general_log
general_log_file=queries.log

I have executed the same in console too with admin privilege but nothing happened, no error was either produced.

Comment: `general_log` should be set to `0` for no log, or to `1` for logging. You need to change it to  `general_log=1`  ( [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_general_log) )

Comment: @Luuk already tried that, but no effect

Comment: With the settings you provided, the file should be created in de `datadir` (use `show variables like '%datadir%';` to show where that is)

Comment: And, you should check if the variables are set with `show variables like '%general%';`  (because it is easy to change the wrong my.ini or my.cnf file....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added at the bottom of ***my.ini*** and restarted MySQL

```
[mariadb]
general_log=1
log_output=FILE
general_log_file=queries.log
```

File created under **mysql\data\queries.log**

Comment: *and restarted* is the key :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using wamp server on windows 10.

Open my.ini file located in C:\wamp64\bin\mariadb\mariadb10.4.10\my.ini

Add the below code at the bottom of this file It will enable slow query logging to the file.

```
[mariadb]
slow_query_log=1
log_output=FILE
slow_query_log_file=c:/wamp64/logs/mariadb_slow.log
long_query_time=2
log_queries_not_using_indexes=ON
```

Restart MariaDB service to apply these changes. Reference https://mariadb.com/kb/en/slow-query-log-overview/